# A very low mass object hits a very high mass non-moving object in a perfectly inelastic collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, collision

If a very low mass object hits a very high mass object (the high mass object is still before the collision), does that mean that in $x$ seconds, where $x$ is a very big number the high mass object can move a very big distance.

For example:

If a fly hits a standing truck in a perfectly inelastic collision, would that mean that the truck will move let's say 1 metre or more in x seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be true in outer space, where there were no resistive forces.  But in reality the small force from the fly wouldn't be able to start the truck moving due to all the resistive forces, friction in the wheels etc...